# Detect scrolling to end of a list with NotificationListener

Tags: flutter, listview, events, scroll

I have a list view that show limited number of items. When the user scroll to the end I wanted to load next batch of items to the list.

I decided to use "NotificationListener" for this.

With the following code I was able to detect user reaching the end  .

```
  @  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 430,
      child: NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
        child: ListView.builder(
          controller: controller,
          physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          itemCount: widget.resList.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, int index) {
            return GestureDetector(
              onTap: null,
              child: ReservationListTile(),
            );
          },
        ),
        onNotification: (ScrollNotification notification) {
          print(notification.metrics.pixels);
          if (notification.metrics.atEdge) {
            
            if (notification.metrics.pixels == 0) {
              print('At left');
            } else {
              print('At right');
            }
          }
          return true;
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

What I hoped was, when the user reach the end of the list she will swipe the list again and there is a trigger to detect that and I would be able to load the next set of items.

The problem I have is when the user reached the end,  the edge event get triggered multiple times.

Is there a way to detect the user pulling the list back?

Comment: Getiing the same problem/ issues ? Is there any proper solutions on this. ? Any ideas

Answer (score 3):

I had a very similar requirement, and I used a listener to detect when the user reached the end of the list. I actually decided not to wait until the user reaches the very end to provide a smoother user experience, so for example at 80% I already add the new items to the list.

See the following code. If you change _scrollThreshold to 0.75 for example, you will see the print statement executing. This is the place where you can add the new items.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => const MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: MyWidget(),
          ),
        ),
      );
}

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  MyWidgetState createState() => MyWidgetState();
}

class MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  static const _itemCount = 32;
  static const _scrollThreshold = 1.00;
  late final ScrollController _scrollController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _scrollController = ScrollController();
    _scrollController.addListener(_scrollListener);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollController.removeListener(_scrollListener);
    _scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => SizedBox(
      height: 400,
      child: Center(
          child: ListView.builder(
              controller: _scrollController,
              physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemCount: _itemCount,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, int index) => Card(
                    child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
                        child: Center(child: Text('Item $index'))),
                  ))));

  void _scrollListener() {
    if (_scrollController.offset >=
            _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent * _scrollThreshold &&
        !_scrollController.position.outOfRange) {
      print('Scroll position is at ${_scrollThreshold * 100}%.');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In my solution I have something like a paged list view. So I can't load the next batch automatically. What I would like to do is detect user pulling the last item in the list. That will load the next batch.

Comment: can anyone provide some help on this?

Comment: With the above code you can detect when the user reaches the end with `_scrollThreshold = 1.00`. I am not aware of a solution that detects an additional pull at the end of the list. If you find it out, please share it here if you can. Thank you.