# Flutter - Define last frame event when scrolling in ListView.Builder

Tags: android, flutter, dart

There is a ListView.Builder that creates a list of 10,000 rows. Each line contains an icon and a Container with the text "index - N". I need that when shifting or scrolling (swipe), the text in the Container is written only on the last frame of the shift or scrolling (swipe) -  not on the last line/entry in the list, but on the last frame/screen update ListView.Builder.

How to find out the event of the last frame when shifting and scrolling (swipe) in ListView.Builder, so that it is on the last frame that the text is displayed in the Container?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: ListViewBuilder());
  }
}

class ListViewBuilder extends StatelessWidget {

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(  
    body: ListView.builder(
      itemCount: 10000,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return  Row(
          children:[
            const Icon(Icons.list),          
            SizedBox(
              height: 30,
              width: 200,
              child: Text('  index - $index'),
            ),
          ],
        );
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

I looked at the Flutter documentation and searched online about it, but didn't find anything.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect scrolling to end of a list with NotificationListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75259462/detect-scrolling-to-end-of-a-list-with-notificationlistener)

Comment: I need to do this not on the last line in the list, but on the last screen update when swiping.